# Unittest and mocks, how to reset them?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I am testing a class that needs a mock in the constructor, so I usually do this:

```
class TestActionManager(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('actionlib.SimpleActionClient', return_value=create_autospec(actionlib.SimpleActionClient))
    def setUp(self, mock1):
        self.action_manager = ActionManager()
```

Then in this class I add all the tests. So the first one is working fine

```
    def test_1(self):
        self.action_manager.f()
        self.action_manager.f.assert_called_once()
```

But if I add another test and run both

```
    def test_2(self):
        self.action_manager.f()
        self.action_manager.f.assert_called_once()
```

It says f has been called twice. I was expecting setUp to create a new ActionManager (and hence create a new mock) before starting every test, but it is clearly not happening, since the mock is somehow shared. Also I tried to do

```
def tearDown(self):
    del self.action_manager
```

But it does not fix the problem.

I have read something related in
[Python Testing - Reset all mocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051263/python-testing-reset-all-mocks)
where the solution is to use a different library (something that I would like to avoid)

and in [Any way to reset a mocked method to its original state? - Python Mock - mock 1.0b1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746431/any-way-to-reset-a-mocked-method-to-its-original-state-python-mock-mock-1-0) where it is using different classes to do it.

Is there any possibility to reset the mock in the same class before or after every test?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is [`reset_mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.reset_mock)

Here's, in general, how it works:

```py
def test_1(self):
    f = MagicMock()  # or whatever you're mocking
    f()
    f.assert_called_once()
    f.reset_mock()
    f()
    f.assert_called_once()
```

The result will be `PASSED`

If you want to automate, then you store the mocked thing inside `setUp`, and in `tearDown` you call the mocked thing's `.reset_mock()` method.

```py
def setUp(self, mock1):
    self.mock1 = mock1
    # ... do other things ...

def tearDown(self):
    self.mock1.reset_mock()
```